# Tikz: How to Align the Text of simple Nodes?

Tags: tikz-pgf, vertical-alignment, nodes

I tried to put up a nice little graphic, to make an example for String-Matching. My Problem is the "b" is not aligned with a and c and i can't find a way to handle this:

```
\begin{figure}[h]

            \begin{tikzpicture}[align=bottom,shorten >=1pt,node distance=1cm,on grid,auto]
              \node(q_0) {$c$};
              \node(q_1) [right of=q_0] {$b$};
              \node(q_2) [right of=q_1] {$a$};
              \node(q_3) [right of=q_2] {$c$};
              \node(q_4) [right of=q_3] {$b$};
              \node(q_5) [right of=q_4] {$a$};
              \node(q_6) [right of=q_5] {$b$};
              \node(q_7) [right of=q_6] {$a$};

              \node(t_0) [below of=q_0]{$a$};
              \node(t_1) [right of=t_0] {$c$};
              \node(t_2) [right of=t_1] {$b$};
              \node(t_3) [right of=t_2] {$a$};
              \node(t_4) [right of=t_3] {$a$};
              \node(t_5) [right of=t_4] {$c$};
              \node(t_6) [right of=t_5] {$b$};
              \node(t_7) [right of=t_6] {$a$};
              \node(t_8) [right of=t_7] {$c$};
              \node(t_9) [right of=t_8] {$b$};
              \node(t_10) [right of=t_9] {$a$};
              \node(t_11) [right of=t_10] {$b$};
              \node(t_12) [right of=t_11] {$c$};

              \path[->] (q_0) edge node {$\neq$} (t_0);
              \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{figure}
```

Comment: There is no `align=bottom`. Instead add `every node/.append style={text height=2ex,text depth=0.5ex}` to the picture options.

Comment: @cfr sadly it didnt work but percusse`s did thanks guys

Comment: @Daniel I know. I deleted it before reading your comment because I tried it and couldn't get it to work. See page 229 of the manual for why I thought it might. Also, I used this for something yesterday and *that* seemed to work so now I'm really very confused!

Comment: @Daniel Apparently `on grid` redefines the anchors? (I don't entirely understand the explanation in the docs...)

Answer (score 6):

You can use

```
every node/.style={font=\strut}
```

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=10pt]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    shorten >=1pt,
    every node/.style={font=\strut},
    node distance=1cm,
    auto
  ]
  \node(q_0) {$c$};
  \node(q_1) [right of=q_0] {$b$};
  \node(q_2) [right of=q_1] {$a$};
  \node(q_3) [right of=q_2] {$c$};
  \node(q_4) [right of=q_3] {$b$};
  \node(q_5) [right of=q_4] {$a$};
  \node(q_6) [right of=q_5] {$b$};
  \node(q_7) [right of=q_6] {$a$};

  \node(t_0) [below of=q_0]{$a$};
  \node(t_1) [right of=t_0] {$c$};
  \node(t_2) [right of=t_1] {$b$};
  \node(t_3) [right of=t_2] {$a$};
  \node(t_4) [right of=t_3] {$a$};
  \node(t_5) [right of=t_4] {$c$};
  \node(t_6) [right of=t_5] {$b$};
  \node(t_7) [right of=t_6] {$a$};
  \node(t_8) [right of=t_7] {$c$};
  \node(t_9) [right of=t_8] {$b$};
  \node(t_10) [right of=t_9] {$a$};
  \node(t_11) [right of=t_10] {$b$};
  \node(t_12) [right of=t_11] {$c$};

  \path[->] (q_0) edge node {$\neq$} (t_0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

But I would use a matrix to position the nodes

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=10pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[shorten >=1pt,auto]
  \matrix[
      matrix of math nodes,
      row sep={1cm,between origins},
      column sep={1cm,between origins}
    ](m){%
      c&b&a&c&b&a&b&a\\
      a&c&b&a&a&c&b&a&c&b&a&b&c\\
   };
  \path[->](m-1-1)edge node{$\neq$}(m-2-1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: +1 I like this. I always think matrices look neat as solutions yet I've never used one. (I think it is the name - I assume they are irrelevant if I'm not doing maths!)

Answer (score 2):

I think the matrix of nodes is a more elegant solution, but a less elegant alternative would be to use `base right=of` from the `positioning` library rather than `on grid`.

```
\documentclass[border=5pt,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[shorten >=1pt,node distance=1cm]
      \node(q_0)  {$c$};
      \node(q_1) [base right=of q_0] {$b$};
      \node(q_2) [base right=of q_1] {$a$};
      \node(q_3) [base right=of q_2] {$c$};
      \node(q_4) [base right=of q_3] {$b$};
      \node(q_5) [base right=of q_4] {$a$};
      \node(q_6) [base right=of q_5] {$b$};
      \node(q_7) [base right=of q_6] {$a$};

      \node(t_0) [below of=q_0]{$a$};
      \node(t_1) [base right=of t_0] {$c$};
      \node(t_2) [base right=of t_1] {$b$};
      \node(t_3) [base right=of t_2] {$a$};
      \node(t_4) [base right=of t_3] {$a$};
      \node(t_5) [base right=of t_4] {$c$};
      \node(t_6) [base right=of t_5] {$b$};
      \node(t_7) [base right=of t_6] {$a$};
      \node(t_8) [base right=of t_7] {$c$};
      \node(t_9) [base right=of t_8] {$b$};
      \node(t_10) [base right=of t_9] {$a$};
      \node(t_11) [base right=of t_10] {$b$};
      \node(t_12) [base right=of t_11] {$c$};

    \path[->] (q_0) edge node {$\neq$} (t_0);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: aligned nodes]

Optically, these do not look aligned to me but it seems they are when I put a box around them in my viewer!